# Test to check that executing a function does not raise an exception

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.x

I have the following function:

```
def create_dic():
    key_list = ['a','b']
    val_list = [1, 2]
    dic = {}
    for i in range(2):
        dic[key_list[i]] = val_list[i]
        
    return dic
```

I want to implement a test that makes sure there are no errors raised in the process of creating the dictionary.

I thought that I could test:

1. Length of output is 2.
2. The keys of the output dictionary are in key_list.

Passing these two tests would do the job.

Is there a standard way to test that a function 'runs'?

Comment: What does "runs" mean? You want to test that the function does what it's supposed to? Or just that it doesn't raise an exception?

Comment: I mean the second, that it doesn't raise an exception.

Comment: So you want to test that a function doesn't raise an exception. Most test systems will count the test as failed if the test raises an exception. So you can just call the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function supplies a result, the usual practice is to test that result.

If it doesn't, you don't have to do anything after the call.

If your testing framework forces you to fill in the "then" part of the standard unit test format anyway, well, Python has `pass` for precisely this situation.

Comment: The usual practice is to test that result, and to test that no unexpected excecptions are thrown.

Comment: @DocBrown what would you do to test create_dic (the function in the question)?

Comment: @Mencia: what I already wrote above: test the result (keys *and* values), and no exceptions. How to do this precisely in code might be a question for Stackoverflow, but not for Softwareengineering.SE, where coding questions are 100% off topic.

Comment: ... if this is only about exceptions: do you use a unit testing framework? Or do you implement and run your tests without any framework?

Comment: @DocBrown fair enough + I did not ask how to code it. I use unit testing. I was just curious about what kind of test you do when you only want to check that you did not break the function in the last change. And this has been answered. I also do other kinds of tests that are more involved. Thanks everyone.